# How to get drag + drop Javascript code to apply to each individual task item, making each list item draggable, rather than items together in block?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, list, drag-and-drop

My drag and drop code does not apply to each new added list item individually, but instead applies to all the list items in one block. However, the purpose of the drag and drop is to make the list items individually sortable and draggable. Any clue to how to correct the code to apply to each new task/list item that is appended under the 'To Do' list?

```js
  var $addButton = $(".btn-primary");
  var $removeButton = $(".btn-danger");
  var $todoList = $(".uncomplete");
  var $doneList = $(".completed");

//Take Text Input and Add <li> to To Do List
 $addButton.on("click", function(){
  
  //Creating object Variables 
  var $sort = $(".sort").val();
  var $newTask = $(".newTask").val();
  var $taskDescr = $(".taskDescr").val();
  var $taskDate = $(".taskDate").val();
 // var $category= $(".category").val();
  var $category= $("input[type='radio'][name='category']:checked").val();
  //var $importance = $("input[type='checkbox'][name='importance']:checked").val();
  var $importance = $('<input type="checkbox" name="importance"/>').val();
  var $newTaskString = $sort + ", " + $taskDescr + ", " + $newTask + ", " + $taskDate + ", " + $category + ", " + $importance + "  "; 
  var $todoList = $(".uncompleted");
  
   //call append method on $todoList
   
  $todoList.append("<li>" + $newTaskString + "<button><span> Done</span></button><button><span> Remove</span></button></li>").addClass("todo");
  
//drag and drop array 
function allowDrop(e)
{
    console.log("allow drop");
    e.preventDefault();
}

function drop(e)
{
    console.log("drop");
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = e.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    e.target.appendChild(document.querySelector("#" + data));
}

function drag(e)
{
    console.log("dragging");
   //e.preventDefault();
    e.dataTransfer.setData("text", e.target.id);
}

function showAllUsers(){
    let allUsersDiv=document.querySelector("#allUsersDiv");

    for(var i=0; i < allUsers.length; i++)
    {
    var newUserDiv=document.createElement("DIV");

        newUserDiv.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
        newUserDiv.setAttribute("ondragstart", "drag(event)"); //"editUser(this)"
        newUserDiv.setAttribute("id", ("userdiv-" + i));

        newUserDiv.setAttribute("style", "border:1px solid red;");

        var newUserEditLink = document.createElement("A");
        newUSerEditLink.setAttribute("href", "#");
        newUSerEditLink.setAttribute("onclick", "editUSer(this)");
        newUserEditLink.innerHTML = "Edit";

        newUserEditLink.setAttribute("id", ("edit-", + i));

        newUserDiv.innerHTML=allUsers[i].username;
        newUserDiv.appendChild(nowUserEditLink);

        allUsersDiv.appendChild(newUserDiv);
}
}
```

```html
  <div class="list-wrap" contenteditable="false"> 
  <div class="list-inner-wrap">
  <h2 class="title">ToDo List</h2>
  <h3 class="title">Add Task</h2>
  <!--<h4>Task Name</h4>-->
  
  <label for="sort">Sort Order:</label><input type="text" class="sort" 
   name="sort" id="sort" value="" placeholder="A,B,C,etc.">
  <br> </div></div>

   <button class="btn btn-primary">
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"> Add</span>
 </button>

   <h3 class="title">To Do</h2>
        <h6><i>Click task item to edit or modify</i></h6>

        <!--Change color of editable task -->
        <div id='div' contenteditable='false' oninput='change()'>

        <div id="allUsersDiv" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondrop="drop(event)" style="position:absolute;left:5px;top:450px;height:200px;width:500px; border: 1px solid black">
        <div draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
   

      <ul class="uncompleted" contenteditable="false" id="id01" >
        <li>Need to be completed task 
        <button class="btn btn-success">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"> Done</span>
          </button>

          <button class="btn btn-danger">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"> Remove</span></button>

          <br>
        
        </li></ul>
        </div></div></div>
```